# Creating StringVar Variables in a Loop for Tkinter Entry Widgets

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have a small script that generates a random number of entry widgets. Each one needs a StringVar() so I can assign text to the widget. How can I create these as part of the loop since I won't know ahead of time as to how many there will be?

```
from Tkinter import *
import random
root = Tk()
a = StringVar()
height = random.randrange(0,5)
width = 1

for i in range(height): #Rows
    value + i = StringVar()
    for j in range(width): #Columns
        b = Entry(root, text="", width=100, textvariable=value+i)
        b.grid(row=i, column=j)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you aware you don't have to use `StringVar`s with entry widgets? Unless you're using the same variable for more than one widget, you don't need them at all.

Comment: I recommend taking a loot at the [`Entry` API](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm), specifically the parts about `delete` and `insert`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is to use a list or dictionary to store each instance of `StringVar`.

For example:

```
vars = []
for i in range(height):
    var = StringVar()
    vars.append(var)
    b = Entry(..., textvariable=var)
```

However, you don't need to use `StringVar` with entry widgets.  `StringVar` is good if you want two widgets to share the same variable, or if you're doing traces on the variable, but otherwise they add overhead with no real benefit.

```
entries = []
for i in range(height):
    entry = Entry(root, width=100)
    entries.append(entry)
```

You can insert or delete data with the methods `insert` and `delete`, and get the value with `get`:

```
for i in range(height):
    value = entries[i].get()
    print "value of entry %s is %s" % (i, value)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just store them in a `list`.

```
vars = []
for i in range(height): #Rows
    for j in range(width): #Columns
        vars.append(StringVar())
        b = Entry(root, text="", width=100, textvariable=vars[-1])
        b.grid(row=i, column=j)
```

That said, you should probably be storing the `Entry` widgets themselves in a `list`, or a 2D `list` as shown:

```
entries = []
for i in range(height): #Rows
    entries.append([])
    for j in range(width): #Columns
        entries[i].append(Entry(root, text="", width=100))
        entries[i][j].grid(row=i, column=j)
```

You can then assign text to each widget with the `insert()` method:

```
entries[0][3].insert(0, 'hello')
```